How to add postprocessing step to AutoFixture for an object of a particular type after all it's properties has been populated?
I use AutoFixture in my tests and need to generate an object with a particular rules.
I have an object with a few nested properties that contain objects. Business rules are such that one property in each of the nested objects must have a value that is equal to the value of a property from the root object.
Consider:
public class Root {
  public string Number { get; set; }
  public Nested1 Nested1 { get; set; }
  public Nested2 Nested2 { get; set; }
}

public record Nested1 {
  public string Number { get; init; }
}
public record Nested2 {
  public string Number { get; init; }
}

The following rule must follow:
Root.Number == Root.Nested1.Number == Root.Nested2.Number
Is it possible to customize the generation of the Root object such that Nested1.Number and Nested2.Number properties have the same value as in Root.Number?

You can use Customize method in Fixture class. Here's example customization:
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    // Arrange
    var fixture = new Fixture();

    fixture.Customize<Root>(composer =>
    {
        var s = "some string";
        return composer.With(x => x.Number, s)
            .With(x => x.Nested1, new Nested1 { Number = s })
            .With(x => x.Nested2, new Nested2 { Number = s });
    });

    // Act
    var root = fixture.Create<Root>();

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(root.Number, root.Nested1.Number);
    Assert.Equal(root.Number, root.Nested2.Number);
}

UPDATE
We can also implement ICustomization interface:
public class MyCustomzation : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<Root>(composer =>
        {
            var s = "some string";
            return composer.With(x => x.Number, s)
                .With(x => x.Nested1, new Nested1 { Number = s })
                .With(x => x.Nested2, new Nested2 { Number = s });
        });
    }
}

And use it like:
fixture.Customize(new MyCustomzation());


Is it possible to configure it with ICustomization implementation?

@AlekseyUsatov Please see update.

So, if I want to also auto generate nested properties it should be done as follows?
public class MyCustomzation : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<Root>(composer =>
        {
            var s = "some string";
            return composer.With(x => x.Number, s)
                .With(x => x.Nested1, fixture.Create<Nested1>() with { Number = s }))
                .With(x => x.Nested2, fixture.Create<Nested2>() with { Number = s }));
        });
    }
}


@AlekseyUsatov I did not test it, but look correct :)
